# With Java Streams, can I filter a list of objects based on a variable that is shared with a secondary list of objects with that same variable?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if there is a way to simply the following code into a stream of some kind to work with, instead of having the for loop?

I am basically looking to filter out a certain group of Swimmers, while trying to also make sure that these swimmers are not already in the "AttendingList."

```
List<Swimmer> swimmingList = //List generated from db;
List<SwimmerAttending> attendingList = //List generated from db;

for(SwimmerAttending s : attendinglist)
   {
     swimmingList = swimmingList.stream()
                                  .filter(i-> i.getSwimerNumber() > 1000 && !s.getSwimmerNumber().equals(i.getSwimmerNumber()))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());   
   }
```

So I am curious if there is a simpler way to do this with just using Streams?  Thanks you.

Comment: `swimmingList` and `attendingList` store different types of objects, right?

Comment: Yes, I will edit to make sure that is more clear above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be simplified and, more importantly, can be made to run in linear time, O(n), as opposed to quadratic time, O(n^2), currently, as you've a loop inside a loop (the stream iteration remains a loop, albeit a hidden one).

To get linear time, you should convert your attending list to a set which can then be checked in constant time. As such:

```
swimmingList = //List generated from db;
attendingList = //List generated from db;

Set<Integer> attendingSet = 
   attendingList.stream()
                .map(s -> s.getSwimmerNumber())
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

swimmingList = swimmingList.stream()
                           .filter(i -> i.getSwimmerNumber() > 1000 
                                    && !attendingSet.contains(i.getSwimmerNumber()))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The conversion to a set is linear (one loop) and the filter is also linear which makes a total linear algorithm.

If your swimming list has 1000 entries and your attending list has 1000 entries, your original code would iterate on each of the attending list entries, and for each attendee, iterate over the 1000 swimming list entry, making a total of 1,000,000 iterations. The new code will iterate over the attending list once (1000 iterations) and then iterate over the swimming list once (1000 iterations) with the membership check being done on a set which is constant time on a HashSet, making the total number of operations only 2000.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, and the set example is also a good point.  I didn't realize there was such a difference when using set vs list when performing actions.  So it doesn't seem that we can do everything in  single stream then?

Comment: Yes, the different collection types have different performance characteristics (usually documented in the javadoc) which should be considered to get the best performance out of them. The only way I can think of that you could do away with the first stream conversion would be if your database reading code could return the attending list already as a set.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: This answer is only correct by accident; there's nothing in the `Set` interface that requires `contains` to be efficient, and the general `to[Collection]` collectors explicitly do not make promises about implementations. `collect(toCollection(TreeSet::new))`, by contrast, would provide a guaranteed log(n) for operations. (In the event, I'm pretty sure that `toSet()` uses `HashSet`, so it's going to _work_, but it's not guaranteed.)

Comment: That's true, thanks Chrylis, I'm assuming that a `HashSet` would be returned by `Collectors.toSet()` which is the case in the JDK implementations I checked. I'm editing my answer to make sure that a HashSet is always used.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the `attendinglist` to their swimmer numbers first:

```
List<Integer> attendingSwimmerNumbers = 
    attendingList.stream()
        .map(SwimmerAttending::getSwimmerNumber)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then we can check if each swimmer's number is in the above list using `contains`:

```
 swimmingList = swimmingList.stream()
                              .filter(i-> i.getSwimmerNumber() > 1000 && attendingSwimmerNumbers.contains(i.getSwimerNumber()))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is all assuming that `swimmingList` and `attendingList` store different types of objects. If they store the same type, then it might make sense to override `equals` of `SwimmerAttending` to check equality of the swimmer number. Then you can use `contains` directly on the `attendingList`:

```
 swimmingList = swimmingList.stream()
                              .filter(i-> i.getSwimmerNumber() > 1000 && attendingList.contains(i))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  I appreciate the addition of having a check if both items are the same type.